# Does repeated use of extract() variables need to be initialized?

Tags: php, extract

I'm using extract() to turn associative array names into variables. But I'm wondering if a repeated call to extract() to re-generate the variables is safe enough to depend on, or should the variables be re-initialized?

```
extract($display[0]); // Turn associative array names into variables.
echo $foobaz . "\n";

$foobaz = ""; // Is this necessary? 
extract($display[1]); // Turn associative array names into variables.
echo $foobaz . "\n";

// Or is this safe to use?
extract($display[0], EXTR_OVERWRITE);
```

Comment: What is the safe form?

Comment: Oh wait, I lie. I thought that `extract()` had a safe form. Turns out that it's almost always dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

As long as each $display[i] array has all the fields then you need not re-initialize them. However, please avoid extract at all costs.

Comment: Why avoid extract()? I have an array with many over a dozen variables to use from it. It seems like a simple solution. What is the better alternative?

Comment: Why not just echo $display[1]['foobaz']?

Comment: I confess I do use extract() sometimes, especially when going through database result sets.  I usually use this: extract($row, 3, "db");  This makes every variable have a $db_ in front.  Ex: $db_name, $db_age, etc.  Much cleaner, and since it's database row, you are guaranteed that records will overwrite each time, if you're in a while loop, for example.

Comment: Instead of `$db_field` you could do `$db['field']`, almost just as short.